# COMSOL Cherenkov radiation

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, computational-physics, simulations, software, cherenkov-radiation

As indicated in the title of the discussion, I would like to know if it would be possible to simulate through software based on the finite element method COMSOL Multiphysics the movement of a particle along a dielectric and isotropic material medium.

Comsol Multiphysics is not a particle-in-cell (PIC) code, but I've the analytical expression for current density of a single particle.

$$
\textbf{j}(\textbf{r};t)= -ev\delta(x)\delta(y)\delta(z-v\cdot t)\textbf{z}
$$

I have thought that, in order to implement Dirac deltas, I should use a Gaussian beam (it is a function that is included in the comsol libraries). What physics and studies would you recommend for this purpose (Wave optics, RF, etc.)? Would you recommend another software for this task?

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use COMSOL in particular? For example, do you just want to simulate Cherenkov radiation, or do you actually need a multiphysics simulation because you're already modeling some other phenomena and need to put Cherenkov radiation on top of it?

Comment: It is part of a medium-term task: to obtain the behaviour of the field created by an electron beam within a layer of a nanometric multilayer design. I have been able to design and obtain the behaviour of the TE and TM modes, and I would like to implement this study.

However, though I understand that the problem is somewhat complicated, if there is any software that is more appropriate for this study I would glad to give it a chance.

Comment: You might consider Geant4 for the higher-energy effects (generally, it models the passage of particles through matter), but I'm not sure it contains the RF responses that you want. Note that the energy deposition in matter of electrons of appreciable energy is fairly complicated, and Cherenkov radiation is likely to not be the only (maybe not even the dominant) contributor. You can also have Moller scattering, energy loss through ionization, and bremsstrahlung radiation, for example.

Answer (score 2):

May this be helpful if someone wants to reproduce this phenomena in COMSOL.

Instead of using a certain physical study, try Mathematics>Classical PDEs>Wave Equation>Time Dependent. Then, in variables, define a gaussian pulse with a relatively small sigma parameter (it depends of your domain geometry).

**Parameters**

e=-1.6e-19 [C/m^3]

v0=2.5e8 [m/s]

epsilonr=1.77

mur=1

sigma=10e-8 [m]

**Variables**

rho=e*exp(-x^2/sigma^2)*exp(-y^2/sigma^2)*exp(-(z-v0*t)^2/sigma^2)

You will use it as a source term in Wave Equation study. Then compute for a time parametric sweep, again, it depends of your geometry (for a charged particle with constant velocity you will obtain a maximum just simply dividing the lengthpath by the velocity).

[image]